# difference between Interface S3Client and Class AmazonS3Client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am creating a method that needs a S3 client as a parameter. I do not know what type should I declare it to be.

this is the doc for S3Client https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html

**Ignore since answered** (this is the doc for AmazonS3Client
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html My question is which type is recommended and what are difference between them? Thank you! )

Update:

I find another S3 Client here: `AmazonS3` interface.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html

However, `setObjectTagging` is supported in type `AmazonS3` not but in type `S3Client` .

Does `AmazonS3` provide more functionality than `S3Client`?
What if I need some function in `AmazonS3` not in `S3Client`, or some in `S3Client` not in `AmazonS3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS SDK for Java has two versions: V1 and V2. **AmazonS3Client** is the older V1 version while  **S3Client** is the newer V2 version.

Amazon recommends using V2:

***The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.***

You can find Amazon S3 V2 code examples in the Java Developer V2 DEV Guide here:

[Developer guide - AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html)

(At this point, the Amazon S3 Service guide does not have V2 examples in it.)

In addition, you can find all Amazon S3 V2 code examples in AWS Github here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/s3

If you are not familiar developing apps by using the AWS SDK for Java V2, it's recommended that you start here:

[Get started with the AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html)

(This getting started topic happens to use the Amazon S3 Java V2 API to help get you up and running with using the AWS SDK for Java V2)

**Update**:

You stated: **However, setObjectTagging is supported in type AmazonS3 not but in type S3Client** .

The way to tag an Object in an Amazon S3 bucket by using Java V2 API is to use this code:

```
  // First need to get existing tag set; otherwise the existing tags are overwritten.
     GetObjectTaggingRequest getObjectTaggingRequest = GetObjectTaggingRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(key)
            .build();

GetObjectTaggingResponse response = s3.getObjectTagging(getObjectTaggingRequest);

// Get the existing immutable list - cannot modify this list.
List<Tag> existingList = response.tagSet();
ArrayList<Tag> newTagList = new ArrayList(new ArrayList<>(existingList));

// Create a new tag.
Tag myTag = Tag.builder()
        .key(label)
        .value(LabelValue)
        .build();

// push new tag to list.
newTagList.add(myTag);
Tagging tagging = Tagging.builder()
        .tagSet(newTagList)
        .build();

PutObjectTaggingRequest taggingRequest = PutObjectTaggingRequest.builder()
        .key(key)
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .tagging(tagging)
        .build();

s3.putObjectTagging(taggingRequest);
```